# How do I get the json data from this HttpURLConnection implementation converted from cURL?

Tags: rest, http, curl, network-programming

Hi I have the following cURL

```
curl -X GET --header "api-key: sOmE-API-kEy" "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/uv-index?date=2016-06-01"
```

which I got from the website that provides data for smart nation their website returns proper json data using their forms but i would like to do this via code using an HttpURLConnection so far I am following the code references i found online but it's not working and I couldnt see what's wrong, i get the NetworkOnMainThreadException which I solved by implementing it as an AsyncTask but when I step in android studio debug its now returning with an FileNotFoundException. i also tried using the TrustedManager etc suggested below and it still has the same error. one thing i noticed is when I go to the website and click on the button and look at it in firebug the following is the one that is processessed ...

```
https://apiconsole-prod.apigee.net/smartdocs/v1/sendrequest?targeturl=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.data.gov.sg%2Fv1%2Fenvironment%2Fuv-index%3Fdate%3D2016-06-01&_=1469245322558
```

but if i type directly from the browser the response has something like this...
steps.oauth.v2.FailedToResolveAPIKey%22%7D%7D%7D", "responseStatusCode": "401"

```
    URL url = new URL("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/uv-index?date=2016-06-01");
    urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConn.setDoInput(true);
    urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("api-key", "sOmE-API-kEy");

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(line).append('\n');
    }
    // Chomp the last newline
    buffer.deleteCharAt(buffer.length() - 1);
```

**note apikey renamed for privacy

so in short looking at the header data from firebug how to i complete my http code implementation

```
Accept  
*/*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
DNT 
1
Host    
apiconsole-prod.apigee.net
Origin  
https://developers.data.gov.sg
Referer 
https://developers.data.gov.sg/datagovsg-apis/apis/get/environment/uv-index
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
api-key: sOmE-API-kEy
```

Comment: I managed to solve th NetworkOnMainThreadException using the AsyncTask solution found in 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

the only problem left is i cant get the same result as when I use the website's form...

Comment: Are you try disable Certificate Validation SSL

Comment: not yet i will try now. thanks for the suggestion i will update you about the result soon

Comment: yeah so now i've tried it and it's still returning me with a file not found error it seems the way they do the get is misleading since its using apigee underneath and not direct using the service. i do not know what apigee is for..

Comment: And error 401 is solved?

Comment: not reolved, i've tried all ways of presenting this data

Comment: You should probably have urlConn.setDoOutput(false); for a GET request

Comment: ah thats it! you solved my problem thanks Yuri Schimke!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following...

> You should probably have urlConn.setDoOutput(false); for a GET request
>   – Yuri Schimke 3 mins ago

Thanks so much for all the suggestions!